# Delphi - equivalent to C# DateTime.Now.Ticks method needed

Tags: c#, datetime, delphi

I need to know the ticks value using TSystemTime in delphi. As I can get the same value in c# through DateTime.Now.Ticks. So I am looking for a function or a way to find ticks value using TSystemTime.

Comment: Yes, it does - look into `Winapi.Windows.pas`

Comment: @StefanGlienke: I stand corrected. Doesn't appear to have a tick component, though.

Comment: @StefanGlienke are you talking about GetTickCount function?

Comment: No I was replying to a comment that is now deleted stating that there is no `TSystemTime` in Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TSystemTime, the simplest way to do this is to convert it to a TFileTime & then add an offset. This will get a value that will match a c# DateTime.Ticks value at the same time.

```
function TSystemTimeToCSharpTicks(sTime: TSystemTime): UInt64;
var
  fTime: TFileTime;
begin
  SystemTimeToFileTime(sTime, fTime); //Should check if it returns an error.
  //Result := UInt64(fTime); Not too sure how safe this is depending on the architecture.
  Result := (UInt64(fTime.dwHighDateTime) shl 32) + UInt64(ftime.dwLowDateTime);
  Result := Result + 504911232000000000;
end;
```